# Active directory commands not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory

I have a script which adds a machine to domain, move it to particular Organization Unit and add the machine to Active Directory Group.

The adding to domain and moving to OU is working. **But the machine is not getting added in AD Group.**

**Command I am trying:**

```
$name=gc env:computername
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Passwd" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("abc\user",$secpasswd)
Add-ADGroupMember -id GroupName -Members "CN=$name,OU=POC,DN=abc,DN=com" -Credential $mycreds
```

**Things which I have already done:**

-installed the **Active Directory Domain Services role** in the machine

-**started the active directory web services**

-**then imported the active directory module**

**Error**:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Unable to contact the server. This may be because the server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have Active Directory Web Services running.
At line1: char:1
+Add-ADGroupMember -id GroupName -Members "CN=$name,OU=POC,DN=abc,DN=com"

 +CategoryInfo: ResourceUnavailable:<GroupName:ADGroup> [Add-ADGroupMember],ADServerDownException

 +FullyQualifiedErrorId :ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

I also tried executing other AD commands like Get-ADGroupMember etc, all the Active Directory commands are giving the same error in powershell.

Am i missing something? stuck at this issue. Please guide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all those actions in the same script? Does the `Add-ADGroupMember` work after a reboot of the system? It not an _official_ domain member before that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to minimize complexity at first.  You're moving the computer object within your script, so instead of trying to specify the FQDN of the computer, try using the SAMAccountName instead.  That way if you're having a hitch related to moving the computer, we can remove one possible complication.

On top of that, try specifying an AD Server in your Add-ADGroupMember step.  My thought is that you're conducting the Domain Join, then doing additional actions, well, your system won't have signed on to the new domain yet, so it may have a hard time finding a domain controller.

To reiterate the troubleshooting steps I would try:

1. Try your existing process using the SamAccountName of the computer to add to the group, instead of the FQDN of the computer.  This might be causing the problem.
2. If this does not work, specify the AD Server to contact for adding Group membership, using the `-Server ServerName` parameter.

Comment: @Matt : no Add-ADgroupMember is not working even after a reboot..it fails even after the machine is properly added to domain.

Comment: @RedOne : hey now the active directory module is not getting imported at first go.. it is showing error.. and when i again import it after the error, it is getting imported.. i am not getting why is it executing in the second run?